# Spring Boot3.* /actuator returns 404 not found

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I upgrade springboot2.0 to springboot3.0.
Find a issue, in springboot2.0 , http://localhost:8080/contextpath/actuator is ok, but in springboot3.0 return 404. When add dispatcherservletpath in url is ok ,for example , http://localhost:8080/contextpath/Dispatcherservletpath/actuator is ok.
I',m confused why url should add Dispatcherservletpath in springboot3.0

Am I missing something? Thank you for your help in advance!